# MCP Home range analysis alternative to Animove in QGIS

Tags: qgis, software-recommendations, habitat-modeling

Can some recommend to me a plugin for doing a MCP/Kernal density and grid cell analysis for home range analysis, one that is not Animove, because I have problems with setting Animove up, which is already mentioned in another question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with using ArcMap for this analysis alone, there is a tool called [Minimum Bounding Geometry](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm) (Select Polygon) and [Kernel Density](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-kernel-density-works.htm). I found it to be way simpler than using Sextante/R in QGIS.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, unfortunately I away from my institution so do not have access to ARCGIS, I think I will proceed to analyse the data in R instead.